# Ionic Storage is not working on Android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-storage

I'm new to the Ionic Framework, and I'm doing an app that preserves the user login so it can show a different page when user is logged. And for doing this, I'm saving the user ID into the local storage. 
This works fine when I do `ionic serve` and testing the code on browser, but it doesn't work on my Android device (so I run `ionic cordova run android`). Why? I have set the Storage right by using `IonicStorageModule.forRoot()` in `app.module.ts -> imports[...]`. Here's my code and my Ionic specs:

[image: ionic code]

[image: ionic specs]

Comment: I'm assuming you're setting the local storage in the login page? also, what does the console log state with the storage variable?

Comment: @StephenRomero yes, I'm setting the userID inside the login page. Unfortunately I don't know how to get the log from my phone

Comment: You can plug your android phone in to your computer and if you're using chrome you can go to developer tools and remote devices and click on your device. This link will help:https://medium.com/@michaelgannon_89769/beginners-guide-to-remote-debugging-android-devices-using-chrome-ded1d3aca11a

Comment: @Sebatino, I second with Stephen. Did you store it in the localStorage? Could you please share the code for setting values to storage

Comment: I found the solution to my problem: I just added a `catch()` just after the first `get` and now it works fine. The problem was the result of `userLoggedID` on the very first access that wasn't returning nothing at all, neither  `undefined` nor `null`

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out my problem and built a solution. On the very first access in my app `userLoggedID` is completely empty (it wasn't neither `undefined` nor `null`), so I attached a `catch()` instruction and now the code works fine.

[image]

LOG:
[image]