# In Ionic4 Ionic Data Storage is not working in mobile phones

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-storage

I have attached a images of dashboard that i stored a token value in ionic data storage and i displayed in dashboard. while i seeing in browser its show, but in mobile it didn't show

[Mobile Dashboard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80ZUV.jpg)

[System DashBoard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFxTu.png)

And i also attached code of storing and getting values from Ionic storage

Storing a response values to Ionic Storage

```
// "token":"v7gtljulmg2t4doheuik4c8m7f1xg28n"



this.api.postRequest(loginobj).subscribe(res =>{        

    this.storage.set('token', res[0].message);
```

Getting values from Ionic Storage

//getting values

```
    this.storage.get ('token')   
    .then(res => {   
       this.tokens1 = res;   
     });
```

In Html
In p tag im displaying this value  {{tokens1}}  200.00

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What kind of investigation did you perform? See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028978/ionic-storage-is-not-working-on-android-device).

Comment: i'm also performing a  same format that you do. i dono how to share a image can u explain means i will  share my coding
backDashboard(){
    this.sessionexp();
    this.storage.get('token')
    .then( res => {
      let sesstokens = res;
      if(sesstokens != null){
        this.navCtrl.navigateBack(['/dashboard']);
      }
      else{
        this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(['/login']);
      }  
    });
  }